# How to cast object1<object2> to interface of object1<interface of object2>?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, covariance, contravariance

Lets say I have this arrangement:

```
    public interface ICreatable
    {
        int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Unicorn : ICreatable
    {
        public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ICrudService<T>
        where T : class, ICreatable
    {
        T DoSomething(T t);
    }

    public class UnicornService : ICrudService<Unicorn>
    {
        public Unicorn DoSomething(Unicorn unicorn)
        {
            var createdByUserId = unicorn.CreatedByUserId;

            // ...

            return unicorn;
        }
    }
```

And use it like so:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unicorn = new Unicorn();
        var unicornService = new UnicornService();

        unicornService.DoSomething(unicorn);
    }
```

This runs fine. However, lets say I want to cast `unicornService` as it's interface type of `ICrudService` along with it's generic type to it's interface type as such:

```
        var crudService = unicornService as ICrudService<ICreatable>;
```

I run into problems. This is how it looks:

```
unicornService as ICrudService<Unicorn> --> casts is fine
unicornService as ICrudService<ICreatable> --> casts to null
```

It seems since `Unicorn` derives from `ICreatable` and since `ICrudService<T> where T: class, ICreatable` that it should have no problems working this out. My searches started leading me into Covariance and Contravariances but I'm getting lost at that level.

How can I cast `crudService` to `ICrudService<ICreatable>`?

**Update:**

Using covariance as such:

```
    public interface ICrudService<out T>
```

Then makes intellisense say "Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'ICrudService.DoSomething(T)'. 'T' is covariant." How does this work?

Comment: Try with `ICrudService<out T>` and take a look at [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) to understand what it implies.

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroD'Andria I updated the question. Using the out keyword leads to another problem. Is there something simple I'm overlooking?

Comment: The code you posted as is works fine with `out T` parameter so the problems is in other place.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria No it doesn't.  It uses `T` as a parameter to a method and as a return value, that means it's invariant with respect to `T` and can be neither covariant nor contravariant.

Comment: @Sevy you're right I just see the edit...

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria You didn't need to see the edit; the code in the first revision showed enough to make it clear that it's invariant.

Comment: @Sevy no, at least the code I copy the interface was empty and the problem I see was conversion. Of course now the thing changes.

Answer (score 0):

An `ICrudService<Unicorn>` cannot be treated as an `ICrudService<ICreatable>`.

An `ICrudService<Unicorn>` object is only allowed to accept parameters of type `Unicorn` or subtypes of `Unicorn`, but an `ICrudService<ICreatable>` can accept a parameter of `SomeOtherTypeOfICreatable`.

You `UnicornService` type is allowed to use members specific to `Unicorn`, not just `ICreatable`, since that's the type it restricted it's function to.  That restriction prohibits it from meeting the more general interface's API.

So, in short, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should change DoSomething to accept **ICreatable** instead of T to use **out T** modifier:

```
public interface ICrudService<out T>
    where T : class, ICreatable
{
    T DoSomething(ICreatable t);
}

public class UnicornService : ICrudService<Unicorn>
{
    public Unicorn DoSomething(ICreatable t)
    {
        var unicorn = (Unicorn)t;
        var createdByUserId = unicorn.CreatedByUserId; // or t.CreatedByUserId

        // ...

        return unicorn;
    }
}
```

Please note that this code will throw the exception if non-Unicorn will be passed to UnicornService.

Comment: This is essentially just removing all of the (valuable) type safety that was in the OP's code.  If `DoSomething` really does need the input to be of type `T`, not `ICreatable`, then this change *shouldn't* be done.  The reason it can't be cast to an `ICrudSercice<ICreatable>` is that it doesn't logically do what that interface says objects implementing it must do, so the fact that you cannot cast it to that interface is *a good thing*.  It means your class isn't claiming to have functionality that it doesn't really have.

Comment: @Sevy you're right and that's the point of the covariance, but removing the cast to `Unicorn` from the above method and working only with an `ICreatable` maybe can fit the needs of the OP.

Comment: yes, but OP is definitely need a ICrudSercice<ICreatable>, so either a return T or parameter T should be replaced with ICreatable.